# meteor Error: Description is Required

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm learning to use meteor and have come across this error after experimenting with [meteor-roles](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles) in server side code to allow management of user roles. I am using the Differential Boilerplate.

Even after reversing edits, I am still encountering this error now.

I don't exactly understand what it means by a description being required.

---

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.


/home/ubuntu/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.1care38++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Description is required
    at getErrorObject (packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:417:1)
    at [object Object].doValidate 
(packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:400:1)
    at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as insert] 
(packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:169:1)
    at Function.Factory._create (packages/dburles:factory/lib/factory.js:79:1)
    at Function.Factory.create (packages/dburles:factory/lib/factory.js:87:1)
    at app/server/seeds/items.js:15:15
    at Function._.times (packages/underscore/underscore.js:1093:1)
    at [object Object]._.(anonymous function) [as times] (packages/underscore/underscore.js:1149:1)
    at app/server/seeds/items.js:14:11
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:229:5
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Is there any related code that could be added to your question?

Comment: check your schema and see if there's any field name "Description" is defined

Comment: Go to your schema, and on the description field, put something like `description:{
 type :String // for example,
optional:true
}` or be sure whathever you are inserting have the `description` field

Comment: 'description:{ option: true }' ended up working. Thanks!